# The review queue button redirects to a review queue which I don't have access to

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar

As soon as the new navigation bar was activated to my profile, I immediatly noticed that in the right part of the nav bar, if you click on the review queue button, it redirects me to the "Suggested Edits" queue, even if I didn't reach the 2000 reputation requirements.

[image]

Isn't the expected behavior to redirect over the queues list, instead of a specific queue?

Comment: Same for me....